# Can npm Help Identify the Compatible Version of Primeng for Angular 16 Dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, primeng

When attempting to install `primeng`, I encountered the following error message:

```
npm i primeng
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: target@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from primeng@17.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/primeng
npm ERR!   primeng@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

The reason for this error is that `primeng` requires Angular version 17, while my project is currently using Angular version 16. The relevant dependencies listed in my `package.json` file include:

```json
   "@angular/animations": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~16.2.0",
    "@nx/angular": "16.10.0"
```

To identify which version of `primeng` is compatible with my current Angular version without resorting to trial and error with different versions, I need a method to determine compatibility through npm.

Is there a way for npm to provide information on which version of `primeng` is compatible with the Angular versions specified in my `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command, it should work.

```
npm i primeng --legacy-peer-deps
```